# How to secure a client/ server socket communication

Tags: java, security, sockets, client-server

Assume that client and server apps are running on different machine

Today:

```
// Server will receive the request and cast it as needed
ProxyResponse message = (ProxyResponse) objStream.readObject();

// Update message with some content
...

// Sent it back to client
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(toClient);
oos.writeObject(message);
```

I'd like to further enhance this to make sure data sent out is somehow protected. How would you recommend i approach this?

I am looking for an example of how data passed between client an server be encrypted and decrypted on both ends and sent over an SSL.

Comment: Protected from what? Eavesdropping? Modification by a malicious intermediary?  Please provide some more details about the threats that you are trying to protect against.

Comment: What do you mean by 'somehow protected' exactly? And why do you think you need to do anything if you're going to send it over SSL anyway? Are you aware that that is exactly what SSL already does?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The JDK [provides an SSL socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)  implementation that seems an appropriate place to start.  It's straightforward to use.

Originally, you probably have code like this:

```
final SocketFactory factory = SocketFactory.getDefault();
final Socket socket = factory.createSocket(host, port);
```

You simply change the factory:

```
final SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
final Socket socket = factory.createSocket(host, port);
```

The same is true for `ServerSocketFactory`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [asymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) or [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) based encryption. Look at the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library. Using symmetric key encryption, this would be as simple as each side having a shared key that is used to encrypt the data.

Based on your updated answer, I agree that you should look into `SSLSocket`.

Comment: What's the reason you suggest BouncyCastle over the crypto included within the JRE?

Comment: The original question was vague.  I've since updated my answer.  However, there are situations where it is useful for the client to have more control over the encryption process.  The client may want to generate the public-private key pair, pass along the public key to the server, so the server can validate the client on future connections.  This approach is used by the Google TV Pairing Protocol.  https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/pairing