# How to Receive SSL Socket Data in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

So I just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324860/how-to-secure-a-client-server-socket-communication) post, and it said that you need to make an SSL socket like this:

```
SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
Socket socket = factory.createSocket("computerName", 2282);
```

So I thought that wouldn't work since it seemed way too easy, but it actually didn't raise an error. It did connect to my server, which is currently just using an ordinary socket connection, but it never showed that it received data from it, just that it connected. Here's the code for each:

Client

```
SocketFactory factory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
Socket socket = factory.createSocket("computerName", 2282);
DataOutputStream outputData = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
outputData.writeUTF("1"));
DataInputStream inputData = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
String returnData = inputData.readUTF();
```

Server:

```
Socket socket = server.accept();
DataInputStream inputData = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
DataOutputStream outputData = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
String incomingData = inputData.readUTF();
System.out.println("Received: " + incomingData);
String[] receivedDataArray = incomingData.split("\\s+");
// "1" occurs when the client pings the server.
if (receivedDataArray[0].equals("1"))
    outputData.writeUTF("1");
```

Any idea why it is behaving like this, and how I can fix it?

Comment: maybe flush the outputData?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work. Since you are not using the `SSLServerSocketFactory` to create the server socket. There are couple of things that you should set first before establishing the secure connection, such as CIpherSuite TLS version etc.

For setting the security parameters, you need to create SSLContext and then create a server socket

```
 SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
    SSLServerSocket ssl = (SSLServerSocket) sc.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(
            YOURPORTNUMBER);
```

One more thing, Your IdentityStore and trustStore should be configured properly.